# How to override class method in VBA?

Tags: vba

I have the following three class modules:

**interface:**

```
Private Sub subCall()
End Sub
Public Sub mainCall()
End Sub
```

**parent:**

```
Implements interface
Private Sub interface_subCall()
    Debug.Print "sub call"
End Sub
Public Sub interface_mainCall()
    interface_subCall
    Debug.Print "main call"
End Sub
```

**child:**

```
Implements interface
Public p As New parent
Private Sub interface_subCall()
    Debug.Print "child sub call"
End Sub
Public Sub interface_mainCall()
    p.interface_mainCall
End Sub
```

I want to inherite child from parent and override `interface_subCall()` so that when I call `interface_mainCall()` - inherited method called (not parent).

I tried this code:

```
Dim c As New child
c.interface_mainCall
```

But it is calling parent's `interface_subCall` - printing "sub call" rather than "child sub call".

As far as I understand - there is no inheritance in VBA. If so - could you please advise - how to do it with composition.

Comment: Can you explain more fully the output you do want? You rarely want to call the interface implementation methods directly, rather you would have a interface type variable assigned to a parent or child instance & call across it via  `ifc.subCall()` / `ifc.mainCall()`

Comment: Currently you explicitly call the parents `interface_mainCall` in the child's `interface_mainCall`, if you don't want that don't do it - you can access the parents behavior in the child via the `p` reference.

Comment: I'm assuming he wants `"child sub call"` as output .....  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  Bad thing assumptions :-)

Comment: @QHarr correct. I edited the question

Comment: @AlexK. what I want to do is to avoid duplicating `interface_mainCall`. How can I create a new class which inheriting `mainCall` but overriding `subCall` ? It is normal for python and C++

Comment: You have correctly noted that there is no inheritance in VBA. And with composition you spell out all properties and methods and map them to calls to respective members of the contained object.

Comment: @GSerg thanks you for your comment. I've spent a couple of hours to get it working. Is it just impossible ? It is difficult for me to think in terms of composition (I used inheritance always)

Comment: I see, you expect the parent to call the "overridden" method from the child (as it would happen with virtual methods). That's not going to happen, the parent is a thing in itself and it's not going to be able to call other classes' methods as its own.

Comment: Maybe see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/81979/30872 for inspiration; you would need to make Parent aware of the child, at which point it's not really parent, rather, an "owner of actual implementation". So you could have a method `Init(ByVal impl As Interface)` on the Parent (in the absence of constructors) to which you would pass an instance of Child, and then use it in all parent's methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following approach is the best.

**child class module:**

```
Public Sub subCall()
    Debug.Print "child sub call"
End Sub
```

**parent class module:**

```
Public Sub subCall()
    Debug.Print "sub call"
End Sub
```

**main class module:**

```
Public Sub mainCall(child)
    child.subCall
End Sub
```

Now I can pass `child`/`parent` as argument to `main`:

```
Dim c As New child
Dim m As New main
m.mainCall c

Dim p As New parent
m.mainCall p
```

So I can avoid duplication of `main` code.